# Facebook Social plugin: Login, how to use it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

Facebook has login social plugin,

"The Login Button shows profile pictures of the user's friends who have already signed up for your site in addition to a login button."

hmm silly question? but how does my site know if the user has logged in or not?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Answer (score 0):

> hmm silly question? but how does my site know if the user has logged in or not?

Silly question, no not really. Use Facebook's JS API call `FB.getLoginStatus()` (See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) for determining if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: how would you get the access token using that login social plugin? only way it seems to get the token is to do this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ ?